# gzinflate string compressed via JS

Tags: javascript, php, gzip, pako

I'm trying to compress a massive JS object on the client side via [Pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) and than get it back on the PHP-script.

JS code

```
const save_str = JSON.stringify(massive_object);
const gz_str = pako.gzip(save_str, { to: 'string' });
$.post('/', 
       {data:window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(gz_str)))}, 
       (data)=>{ console.log(data); },
       'json');
```

PHP code

```
$res = gzinflate(base64_decode($_POST['data']));
```

Should be quite straight-forward thing but I keep getting `gzinflate(): data error`.
Already spent a few hours dancing around, still no result. Begging for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `gzdecode()`, not `gzinflate()`.

Comment: @mark thanks a lot, it helped!
Another problem I had was obsolete `unescape` and `encodeURIComponent` usage, base64 encoding seems to be enough, but the main issue was wrong decompressing function used. Have to pay more attention to the theory.

Comment: For some reason that is not working for me. I've tried `gzdecode(base64_decode($stringToInflate));` and `gzdecode($stringToInflate);`