# How to unzip in PHP the data previously zipped in JavaScript

Tags: php, laravel, zlib, pako

I'm trying to compress a JSON string with `pako` and send it to a PHP script (Laravel) and uncompress it, then modify it, compress again and sent it back to client.

When I compress and uncompress in the client, it works perfect; but when I send compressed data from the client to the server, it shows me:

> "ErrorException (E_WARNING) gzdecode(): data error".

I've tried `gzinflate`, `gzumcompress`, `gzuncompress`, [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952929/gzinflate-string-compressed-via-js), `zlib` and `pako` official documentations, but nothing works.

**Client code**:

```js
var pako = require('pako');
// convert JSON to string 
var input = JSON.stringify(vm.exceltojson);
// compressing input
var output = pako.gzip(input, {to: 'string'});
output = btoa(output);
var data = [{output: output}];
// send data to server
HTTP.post(apivalida_per, data)
    .then(response => {
      vm.persona_planilla = response.data.data;
    });
```

**Server code**:

```php
public function getgzip(Request $request)
{
  // here I get the error: gzinflate() data error
  // Example of input on base64 H4sIAAAAAAAAA12SUUvDMBSF/4r0WVw7N9fubU5lheFkqA8TCbdJ1l1Zc0PSyED87960KwyfSr5zzj23TT9+EuMomWfXidVOSEzm02KW380mAxD6ZLVCxaZk/ZL0GKw+HpkJ67DRcUCyWG6Wq3Jb/nd4XQfTpZfbt91ZNdRUTnuG27fX1dVD+fy43i3O4l7LAwgDEhvUpo3R22yUTkdZkRdnjwWM6fvNunwvh6DXp2h+4qOygmSwPINMrCbjw7El10t9A5qad4iJLB+l2WicZkWvH8iB544aFHBN3kGFzFoHFXyBIsbjrDdDxd0VeJQ8azpN0w5XZEiAabEOWoFi+6VgHakg++167EPlUSGJvSPTageDECv5EvhBTqEBxx5Dsg3O0ODhVUkoatCghONAqXXkuz4/ICcFfvPo2XhyM5lduJT2MsSv3Vt1YwWq7r8IXjtUAlp+hd/PP5f0W64xAgAA

  $string = gzdecode(base64_decode($request->output));
  return $string;
  // ---here is more code, but i want first uncompress de JSON
}
```

Comment: Why are you compressing it? The web server and browser should be doing this for you anyway, provided they're configured correctly (normally automagically on).

Comment: @Kurucu because is sending data from the browser UP to the server, not the other way around.

Comment: @Mirko Ah yes. Should have been paying more attention.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `gzdecode()`. That is the PHP function that decompresses gzip streams.

`gzuncompress()` is for zlib streams, and `gzinflate()` is for raw deflate streams. I have no idea why the PHP authors put "gz" in those function names, unless they thought it would be funny to deliberately confuse users.

The example base64 string you provided in the question decodes to a valid gzip stream. So your data was properly compressed and made it across to the server unscathed. `gzip_decode(base64_decode(that))` should work. Are you certain that `$request->output` is that string?

Comment: already try with gzdecode () and it also shows me the data error

Comment: You should post a small example of what you are giving to `base64_decode` on the PHP end.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, and edit the code with the input example

Comment: the example is in the server code, I added a comment line

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed that.

Comment: @jhonchacolla any updates on this? Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You just change code:

```
var output = pako.gzip(input, {to: 'string'});
```

to

```
var output = pako.gzip(input);
```

The `{to: 'string'}` option will be converted from utf8 to utf16 (javascript) string.
@see: https://nodeca.github.io/pako/#inflate